# Ввод текста в другой форме

Tags: delphi

Есть готовая программа которая просит пароль при запуске.

**Теоретически это реально:** Написать программу на Delphi которая бы вводила этот пароль автоматически в эту готовую программу.

Как это сделать ? Или где прочитать ?

Comment: AutoIt в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Windows API по работе с окнами.
Можно найти хендл заголовка окна при помощи функций EnumWindows FindWindow
GetWindowText SetWindowText. (сообщение wm_settext)
Но все зависит от контролов (через какие классы реализованы).
Есть утилитки, которые показывают хендл окон (Spy++) например.

Алгоритм такой:

1. При помощи Spy++ попробовать найти хендл окна ввода
2. Заслать туда текст сообщение из программы
3. Если сработает при помощи `EnumWindows` перебрать окна и найти нужное по классу или тексту заголовка
4. Потом с помощью `FindWindow` и `FindWindowEx` найти контрол
5. Заслать сообщение `WM_SETTEXT`